# Joining tables + SUM & GROUP BY function

Tags: sql

I'm struggling in joining tables together with SUM and GROUP BY function. The query below works fine:

```
select ID, sum(amount)
from table1
group by ID
having sum(amount) between 1000 and 10000
```

As table1 only includes customer ID, I also need to join table CUSTOMERS, which contain customer name (column NAME). Following query will not work for me anymore:

```
select ID, name, sum(amount)
from table1
left join customers on table1.ID = customers.ID2
group by ID
having sum(amount) between 1000 and 10000
```

Ditching `SUM` and `GROUP BY` functionality does "fix" the issue as also column NAME will be available in the result, however I still need to sum and group the AMOUNT based on ID. How should I join the other table in this case to also present field NAME from table CUSTOMERS?

> Column NAME or expression in SELECT list not valid'

is currently given as error message.

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function!

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result!

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be in the `group by`:

```
select t1.ID, c.name, sum(t1.amount)
from table1 t1 left join
     customers c
     on t1.ID = c.ID2
group by t1.ID, c.name;
```

Note the use of table aliases.

Answer (score 0):

Add "name" in group by clause

```
select table1.ID, customers.name, sum(table1.amount) amount
from table1,customers on table1.ID = customers.ID2
group by table1.ID,customers.name
```

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
select t.ID, c.name, sum(t.amount)
from table1 t
left join customers c on table1.ID = customers.ID2
group by t.ID, c.name
having sum(t.amount) between 1000 and 10000
```

or without having depends on your requirement